# How to use SSL in ASP.NET C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, https

I am new to Security in Asp.net application. I want to enable SSL in my asp.net local application i have Developed. i need a step by step implementation to ssl to my asp.net project. Most article i found online has only  explained the installation of the certificate. As a newbie what is the first thing i will do to convert my http to https. Do I need to change anything in the web.config?

Comment: What IIS version? Self signed cert?

Comment: i have got free cert from  startssl just want test for the implement tation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to buy a SSL certificate. That's not free.

Then you need to host in on your local IIS. If you run on Windows, you can activate it in Programs and Features. Then you can install the SSL certificate there (you can find an icon in the IIS manager).

I guess you run the website in Visual Studio, and hosting the website on the IIS is quite different. If you have no experience doing so, I would either recommend starting wih that, or see if you can avoid using the SSL certificate.

Comment: Does these mean that my project must be runing in IIS where the file is in wwwrooot folder not ordinary project created in my VS Project folder.

Comment: for deployment, yes. locally you can use iss express: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx